# Tableau - Running Total for Previous 24 Months

Tags: tableau-api

How can I make something like this? *Note that ordering of Month was dependent in Parameter(Display Date)*. Parameter(Display Date) presents the last month to display.

[image]

Those line represent the following:

[image]

Will this be possible for tableau?

Comment: I wonder why this question was voted not useful. And still no one even tried to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your date field is called **Date** and that the value you're measuring is called **Value**.

You just need two calculated fields:

**Last Year / Current Year**:

```
IF DATETRUNC('month', [Display Date]) >= DATETRUNC('month', [Date])
AND DATEADD('month', -11, DATETRUNC('month', [Display Date])) <= DATETRUNC('month', [Date])
THEN 'Current Year'
ELSEIF DATEADD('year', -1, DATETRUNC('month', [Display Date])) >= DATETRUNC('month', [Date])
AND DATEADD('month', -23, DATETRUNC('month', [Display Date])) <= DATETRUNC('month', [Date])
THEN 'Last Year'
END
```

There's a solid chance that it's possible to shorten that, but it gets the job done. The `DATETRUNC`s are to make sure that dates from the entire month are considered. Note that if a date is not in the current year or last year, then this field will be null.

Toss MONTH(**Date**) in the Columns shelf (make sure it's discrete), and toss SUM(**Value**) in the Rows shelf. Add **Last Year / Current Year** to the Color shelf to split the line into two, and then filter out the nulls for your **Last Year / Current Year** field.

At this point, everything should be working except that your chart starts with January (or the beginning of your fiscal year). We'll need to make a sort field.

**Month Sort Field**:

```
(MONTH([Date]) + (11 - MONTH([Display Date]))) % 12
```

This will assign a number from 1 - 12 to each date, with 12 being the month of **Display Date** and 1 being the month after **Display Date**.

Now right click on the MONTH(**Date**) in the Columns shelf and hit **Sort...**. Go to Field, choose **Month Sort Field**, and your months will sort such that **Display Date** is the final month on the axis.